# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted. Where is the error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im getting the error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Im getting confused, because it's telling me the error is occuring at line 2, i dont see how that is possible?

```
UPDATE .patient_insurance
SET insurance_sequence = CASE def_cob
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Primary'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Secondary'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Fifth'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Sixth'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Seventh'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Eigth'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Ninth'
        END
    ,status_flag = CASE active_ind
        WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END
    ,insurance_company_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM insurance
        WHERE companyname = payer_name
        )
    ,insurance_number = policy_nbr
    ,policy_group = group_nbr
FROM person_payer
    ,person
WHERE person.person_id = person_payer.person_id
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM patient_insurance
        WHERE cast(person_payer_id AS VARCHAR(50)) = isnull(custom_field_22, '')
        )
    AND isnull(custom_field_22, '') = cast(person_payer_id AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: run your subquery by itself and see how many rows it returns.

Comment: You have two subqueries, only one of which follows `=`. (It's important to actually *read the words in the error message* - they contain information that is useful.) Read the queries, figure out which one of the two it is based on that information, and then run that subquery by itself to see what it returns.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
insurance_company_id =
(select id from insurance where companyname = payer_name),
```

It is telling you that that subquery is coming back with more than one row and it can't assign the value of multiple rows to a single column on a single row.

Answer (score 1):

The line numbers in these errors are often meaningless. It usually gives you the position of the statement that started it all, which is probably on line 2 in your case.

Change this to a SELECT in order to view a COUNT() of rows returned by the subquery for each row in your base table. One or more of them has more than one insurance.id that is being returned by your subquery.

For example:

```
select
    person_payer_id,
    payer_name,
    (select count(id) from insurance where companyname = payer_name) as payer_name_count,
    insurance_number = policy_nbr,
    policy_group = group_nbr
from
    person_payer,person
where
    person.person_id = person_payer.person_id
    and exists 
    (
    select
        *
    from
        patient_insurance
    where
        cast(person_payer_id as varchar(50)) = isnull(custom_field_22,'') )
        and isnull(custom_field_22,'') = cast(person_payer_id as varchar(50)
    )
```

Here is a version that isolates these offending subqueries, without regards for the exists() clause.

```
select
    t.*
from
    (
    select
        person_payer_id,
        payer_name,
        (select COUNT(id) from insurance where companyname = payer_name) AS payer_name_count,
        insurance_number = policy_nbr,
        policy_group = group_nbr
    from
        person_payer,person
    where
        person.person_id = person_payer.person_id
    ) AS T
where
    T.payer_name_count > 1
```

Simpler still, a query on insurance will find the problems in this case.

```
SELECT
  companyname,
  count(*)
FROM
  insurance
GROUP BY
  companyname
HAVING
  count(*) > 1
```

Also, please do something about the code formatting. Formatting is free, and avoids maintenance nightmares. This code is very hard to read for the next person (which just might be you).

Comment: Thanks, I did not write the original query. Will clean up, i agree! When i ran a count i'm only getting 1 in every payer name count, which is why i am getting confused?

Comment: remove the exists() clause and try that. The machine may be running the primary query, with subqueries, then applying the exists() clause to that resulting set. This could also be modified to return only those that are offending, for ease. I will edit my post.

Comment: Incidentally, you will sometimes also see this behavior with data type conversions, such as CAST() on a varchar to a datetime. Even if your final set contains no offenders, the intermediate sets, or scanned rows, often do.

Comment: @DDulla please accept the answer if it worked for you. That's how this site works.